# Simple SQL Server query hanging after a certain index. What's going on?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64). I have this simple table in SQL Server which according to its storage property has only 2910 records.

[image]

I've come across what is perhaps the weirdest performance issue in my experience thus far and have no way to tell what's happening: any query "beyond" row 2100 in the default order simply hangs indefinitely. This is happening in ONLY one of our environments, nowhere else.

So, what I am saying is that if I query:

```
SELECT TOP 2100 *
FROM [Rapids].[everest].[UserData]
```

→ 2100 rows and query finishes execution in no time.

While

```
SELECT TOP 2101 *
FROM [Rapids].[everest].[UserData]
```

→ query hangs indefinitely.

As I said, we are on SQL Server 2008 R2, so I can't use `OFFSET/FETCH NEXT`, but if I do my offset manually, I still get the same behaviour.

Let's say that the penultimate record of the first 2100 returned in the successful query has `Id = 2324`, if I query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [Rapids].[everest].[UserData]
WHERE Id > 2324
```

→ 1 row,  corresponding to the last one of the first 2100.

And the following hangs:

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM [Rapids].[everest].[UserData]
WHERE Id > 2324
```

→ query hangs indefinitely.

I'm really puzzled, and as I said, this is happening in only 1 environment, which leads me to believe this table is "corrupted" in some way.

Comment: Try updating statistics.

Comment: @TabAlleman: You, Sir, rock. :)

Comment: Ha!    Lucky guess.   :)